# Are uninitialized globals always default to 0 in c?

Tags: c, elf

I know that uninitialized globals are restored in the BSS segment and the OS **should** initialize it to zeros.

But it's **should** not **must**,and I've never seen any standard saying that uninitialized globals **must** be default to zeros, so is it safe to take this as granted?

Comment: BSS is a detail of *how* an implementation can meet the requirement that non-explicitly-initialized objects of static storage duration have initial values of zero, nothing more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the autoritative answer from the [C99 Standard Document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) clause 6.7.8 (paragraph 10):

If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
indeterminate. If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized explicitly,
then:

- if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
- if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
- if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules;
- if it is a union, the ﬁrst named member is initialized (recursively) according to these
  rules.

Comment: The additional information required is that objects declared at file scope always have static storage duration.

Answer (score 3):

The C standard says that variables with static storage duration (which includes all global variables) without explicit initialization are initialized to zero.

Other languages, such as Fortran, differ.

Comment: @compile-fan: What makes you think non-static global variables exist in C?

Comment: "static" is ambiguous, when someone says "static variables" it's not always clear whether they mean those with static storage duration (which includes all globals), or function-local static variables (hence also with static storage duration), or perhaps just globals declared using `static` (and hence with internal linkage). All of them have static storage duration, of course, but depending which meaning you pick, some or all globals might be "non-static".

Comment: @Steve: Fair enough; The (apparently not-so-obvious) point was that all global variables have static storage duration.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC there's certainly no requirement that uninitialised globals be set to zero, and I'm sure I've heard of cases where that's not the case. As always, play it safe and always initialise your variables yourself if you're afraid of it being an issue.

I personally try to **never** take anything for granted. Not only does making it explicit neatly circumvent any such troubles, but it also makes it clear for anyone else reading your code what you are expecting to be the case.

**EDIT:** I've since been corrected that the standards *do* require globals to be initialised to zero. Just to clarify my poor wording above, I don't mean that absolutely nothing can ever be taken for granted (that's absurd), but rather that if there is a simple and concise way of *not* taking something for granted, do it.

The reason I advocate this approach is because although most programmers can rely on compilers with standards-compliant behaviour, there are plenty of us that work in environments where standards compliance is not always possible for whatever reason (the hardware limitations of microcontrollers being a good example, or see Steve's example in the comments). I'd also argue that there's not in existence any compiler that is fully standards compliant (other than in those cases where a compiler *defines* the standard).

When I see `int myGlobal=0;` in a file, I know *for sure* that `myGlobal` has a value of zero. If it is just declared as `int myGlobal;`, the standard says that is also *should* have a value of zero. That does not guarantee that it *will*, and I believe that typing the extra two characters is no big cost, increases readability of the program, and increases portability if you find you ever do need to compile the code on a platform that doesn't pre-initialise globals. *That* is my point - why not, and you might just cover yourself even if the standard says you *should* be ok.

Comment: "cases where that's not the case" - that could be non-conforming implementations, for example on an OS without a good concept of a process, where each executable has only a single, system-wide set of globals. Then when `main` is entered, each global would contain whatever it contained last time `main` exited. One of my colleagues had the pleasure of porting quite a lot of C code to such a system once.

Comment: -1 this is simply wrong. By your reasoning, I guess I'd also better not take for granted that `2+2` yields 4...

Comment: @R: Yep, I'll agree that given that I wasn't aware of the requirements of the standard, you probably can take for granted that your globals will be initialised to zero in a standards-conforming environment. Steve's comment just goes to prove my point though - there's times and places where you can take things for granted (2 + 2 is an example: it simply doesn't make sense for it to be anything but 4), but this is **not** one of them.